# Duplicate notifications in the notification bar in the background

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I am working on implementing push notifications using FCM and flutter_local_notifications in Flutter. I am testing on Android only for now. The notifications work fine in the foreground, but when the app is in the background, I receive the notification only once, but it appears duplicated in the notification bar.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:label="flutter_weather"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
                <meta-data
           android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
           android:value="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is my **`main.dart`**:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'package:flutter_weather/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter_weather/screens/notification_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_weather/screens/test_screen.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class WeatherApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherApp({super.key});

  @override
  createState() => _WeatherAppState();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await setupFlutterNotifications(); // setting method
  showFlutterNotification(message); // local notification
}

// FCM foreground processing - Show local notification
void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;

  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: '',
        ),
      ),
      payload: message.data["screen"],
    );
  }
}

late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false; 

// setting method
Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
  );
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    const InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
    ),
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onTabNotification,
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onTabNotification,
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);


  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
  getToken();

  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

// Function to navigate when notification is clicked
void onTabNotification(NotificationResponse details) async {
  if (details.payload != null) {
    print('onDidReceiveNotificationResponse - payload: ${details.payload}');
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed("/${details.payload}");
  }
}


Future<void> getToken() async {
  // ios
  String? token;
  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
    token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken();
  }
  // aos
  else {
    token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  }
  print("Token: $token");
}

void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
  // navigate to new screen when message is received and user tabs notification
  if (message != null) {
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(
      "/${message.data["screen"]}",
      arguments: message,
    );
  }
}

void main() async {
  await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const WeatherApp());
}

class _WeatherAppState extends State<WeatherApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(showFlutterNotification);
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "title",
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/notification_screen": (context) => const NotificationPage(),
      },
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: const TestScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my JSON:

```
{
"notification": {"title": "background ",
"body" : "background test 123123", "alert":"true},
"priority": "high",
"data": {
"type": "notification",
"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "screen": "notification_screen",
    "id": "1"},
    "to": "MY_DEVICE_TOKEN"
}
```

The issue seems to be related to how I handle background messages in `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` and the setup of notification channels in `setupFlutterNotifications`. I've tried various solutions, but the problem persists.

I came across a suggestion to remove the 'notification' field, so I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: try removing the callback assignment in `main()`. I see it is also defined in `WhatherApp` `initState()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of this line

```
 showFlutterNotification(message);
```

This means you are showing the message twice. Once FCM and once again through local notifications

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
Until now, I had been testing only on the emulator. When I tried it as you suggested, the heads-up notification didn't appear, but I could only check the notification by pulling down the status bar. However, when I tested it on a real device instead of the emulator, it worked correctly. What could be the reason for this?